# Record audio/video fields for contacts?

Tags: custom-fields

I'm using CiviCRM + Drupal 8.

I'd like to be able to add fields to contacts that can record audio &/or video, so that we can collect interviews with our contacts.

Is it possible to add "recording" fields that will allow you to record from within CiviCRM?

If not, what's the best way to set up contact fields to allow you to upload an audio/video file to a contact's record?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about recording directly, but in any case the resulting data would likely be large and would probably run into timeouts or other technical limits. I'd probably suggest storing the video files elsewhere and just adding a custom field to the stock Interview activity type in civi called e.g. "Audio/Video link" that's of type "Link", and then put the url to the video file in that field.